# Exception details search from Log File using Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have to get exception stack trace and the related details from my application log(big size) file.

Say for example I am interested for below mentioed exception and its java stack trace.

**Person does not exist for** 
com.YYYYYYY.adminsubsystem.business.exceptions.AdminSubSystemEntityDoesNotExist: Person does not exist for 
    at com.YYYYYYY.adminsubsystem.business.AbstractDao.doSingle(AbstractDao.java:83)
    at com.YYYYYYY.adminsubsystem.business.individual.dao.jpa.PersonsDaoJpa.getPersonByPrimaryEmail(PersonsDaoJpa.java:43)

So my requirement is , I will provide search string (or any specific exception CODE) - "**Person does not exist for**"

Lucene, will chcek the entire LOG file and returned me the Related Stack trace details(may be more than one occurence) from the file.

Can I achive this using Lucene?  Any sample code will be helpful.

Comment: Lucene seems like a drastic solution...  You can, but it will take a lot of effort/code.  This could be done way easier with command line tools like grep (or findstr in windows) or a scripting language like perl.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty typical case for Lucene.  Certainly would work, and I don't see anything that would be unusual or problematic.  If you are having trouble getting started, there are some [resources available here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/gettingstarted.html).

One thing that does occur to me, Lucene certainly won't have any notion of what a stack trace is.  You will have to define that.  The stack trace seems to be the unit you wish to search and view, so indexing each stace trace as a single document in the index probably makes the most sense.

As @Lucas mentioned, though, if this is for your own, or perhaps other developers, use, it might be gold-plating a bit.  Have you considered just using [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)?